# ANSI escape sequences in PS1 cause incorrect length calculation

Tags: zsh, prompt, escape-characters, readline, ansi

I have a `PS1` set up in my `.zshrc` which includes multiple ANSI escape sequences. An equivalent definition works nicely in Bash, but in Zsh (v5.8.1) it seemingly causes the shell to calculate the width of the prompt incorrectly. As a consequence, when entering longer commands, the command line *suddenly vanishes*, and I am typing blind. And in cases it leads to the cursor being placed on the next line after the prompt, even though the `PS1` does not include a line break.

I am already using the [`\001…\002` escape sequences](https://superuser.com/a/301355/2269) that are used by readline to adjust the length calculation around each ANSI escape sequence. Unfortunately this seems to be insufficient for Zsh (in the example below they don’t seem to have *any* effect, but in my real, more complex `PS1`, they seem to improve the situation *somewhat*, at least).

Here’s an example to demonstrate the issue (the comment underlines the ANSI escape sequence parts that I believe need to be bracketed by `\001…\002`):

```
PS1=$'\001\e[38;2;1;1;1m\e[48;5;250m\002}\001\e[38;5;250m\e[48;2;1;1;1m\002} '
#     \001--------------------------\002 \001--------------------------\002
```

With this prompt, and using an 80 column terminal, after I type 25 characters, the entire command including prompt vanishes. Using backspace does not make the characters reappear, but instead makes the cursor go to the previous line.

[Here’s an Asciinema recording of this behaviour.](https://asciinema.org/a/2GjmnytLQ01UvoqCNbdqwVSxr)

For this demo I have disabled all other customisation of my shell.

(In reality I am using the `nf-pl-left_hard_divider`, U+E0B0, from [NerdFont](https://www.nerdfonts.com/cheat-sheet) instead of the `}`s, but this does not impact the issue.)

What am I doing wrong? How are ANSI escape sequences supposed to be used inside a Zsh prompt definition?

Comment: zsh doesn't use GNU readline, it has its own (much more advanced) line editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `zsh`, you use `%{` and `%}` prompt escapes for that. From [`info zsh 'prompt expansion'`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects):

> `%{...%}`
> Include a string as a literal escape sequence.  The string within
> the braces should not change the cursor position.  Brace pairs can
> nest.
>
> A positive numeric argument between the % and the { is treated as
> described for %G below.

So, that would be `PS1='%{\e[...m%}'` except that you don't need to hardcode escape sequences in zsh, as it has its own prompt expansion operators for most visual effects.

For instance to set the `F`oreground colour to RGB `#010101` and `B`ackground colour 250 from the 256 colour palette, you'd do:

```
PS1='%F{#010101}%K{250}Text%f%k%# '
```

You can use `print -P` which also does prompt expansion, to see what corresponding escape sequences are being generated:

```
$ print -rP '%F{#010101}%K{250}' | sed -n l
\033[38;2;1;1;1m\033[48;5;250m$
```

There's even a `zsh/nearcolor` module to give you the nearest colour for those `#RRGGBB` specifications on terminals that don't support truecolor escape sequences (but support the 256 colour palette):

```
$ zmodload zsh/nearcolor
$ print -rP '%F{#010101}%K{250}' | sed -n l
\033[38;5;16m\033[48;5;250m$
```

Comment: That fixes it, thanks. Incidentally, I’ve been searching for a solution (on and off) for ages, and I read tons of topics here and on SO; the duplicate is unfortunately hard/impossible to find unless you already know exactly what you’re looking for.